# Linq way of checking that no items in a collection match any other item

Tags: c#, linq

I'm taking a collection of line segments and trimming any that overlap and I should get a collection that does not overlap as output.

To test my output I want to iterate over each item in the collection and ensure that it does not overlap with any other item.

Currently I have this code:

```
foreach (var assay in compiledAssays)
{
    if (compiledAssays.Where(a => a != assay).Any(a => a.Overlaps(assay)))
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Something went wrong.");
    }
}
```

It's readable but it "smells bad" to me. Seems like it would be iterating through the collection at least three times to do the test.

Is there a better way of expressing this test?

Comment: Distinct does not work for you ?

Comment: Minor suggestion: [Do not throw `ApplicationException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229007(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, merging the `Where` and the `Any` clauses would be a good first improvement:

```
foreach (var assay in compiledAssays)
{
    if (compiledAssays.Any(a => a != assay && a.Overlaps(assay)))
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Something went wrong.");
    }
}
```

You can also try the more succinct:

```
if (compiledAssays.Any(a => compiledAssays.Any(b => a != b && a.Overlaps(b))))
{
    throw new ApplicationException("Something went wrong."");
}
```

Otherwise, if your primary concern is to minimize the amount of loops that are performed, I wouldn't use Linq.  I would do this instead (assumes `compiledAssays` is an array, adjust as necessary):

```
for (int i = 0; i < compiledAssays.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < compiledAssays.Length; j++)
    {
        if (compiledAssays[i].Overlaps(compiledAssays[j]))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Something went wrong.");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** A very pertinent comment by Raymond Chen.

My last option assumes that the `Overlaps` function is symmetric.

In other words, that `a.Overlaps(b)` will always return the same value as `b.Overlaps(a)`.  If this is not the case, then my last option is incorrect.

Comment: This assumes that `Overlaps` is symmetric (i.e., `a` overlaps `b` if and only if `b` overlaps `a`). Probably true, but worth calling out.

Comment: @Raymond: You are absolutely right.  I got carried away with what the `Overlaps` name means to me, and didn't stop to think that it could be an incorrect assumption.

Comment: good catch on merging Where and Any, that seems like the most immediate improvement

Comment: @Coxy: I added one more option if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your first `Where` clause is excluding exact duplicates (depending upon what `!=` is defined to be for `assay`), as such you can use `compiledAssays.Distinct` as the base enumeration, but given you could use a sort to optimise the search for overlaps anyway, but at the expense of an extra loop, the now accepted answer's explicit double loop is fine, except it doesn't currently exclude all duplicates. It should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < compiledAssays.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < compiledAssays.Length; j++)
    {
        if (compiledAssays[i] != compiledAssays[j]
          && compiledAssays[i].Overlaps(compiledAssays[j]))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Something went wrong.");
        }
    }
}
```

to replicate the OP, again assuming `Overlaps` is symmetric.

Comment: I think that OP's `a != assay` condition is not about filtering duplicates in the list, but simply about ensuring that the `Overlap` check is not performed on itself. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @sstan Probably, but I saw the `.Distinct` "optimisation" before there was an answer but got called away :-( I thought it was worth still answering since my answer does cover the OP's algorithm exactly.

Comment: @sstan yes that's correct, each assay is a plain old object that doesn't override Equals() or anything like that. It's merely to avoid checking for overlap against yourself, because that would return true of course.